# Admin's permission to copy a file into Program Files folder

Tags: windows-7

I tried to copy some files into a subfolder in 'C:\Program Files' folder
but it failed with an error message
'You'll need to provide administrator permission to copy this file'.
I am the only user of this computer and there is only one account in Windows 7 (of course my account)
What's the problem?

Comment: which subfolder ??  not knowing I'll guess it is owned by TrustedInstaller, take ownership and grant yourself permissions.  http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/add-take-ownership-to-explorer-right-click-menu-in-vista/

Comment: @OP: run the copy from an elevated command prompt or via an elevated explorer. (To elevate a programs rights, right click on it and use the "Run as administrator" option).

Answer (score 3):

That is not a problem, it's User Account Control in action. When that is turned on, all users (even those in the administrator's group) normally run as a limited standard user, and administrators must actively give consent for actions that require elevated privileges (such as writing to the Program Files folder).